# SQL Oracle - Find all combination of events possible based on date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, row-number, partition

I have a table with the following information:

Data Sample

```
**Table 1**  
palletNumber-- event-- --recordDate
-----1-----------A-------01/11/2015 01:00
-----1-----------B-------01/11/2015 02:00
-----1-----------C-------01/11/2015 03:00
-----1-----------D-------01/11/2015 04:00
-----2-----------A-------01/11/2015 01:10
-----2-----------C-------01/11/2015 01:15
-----2-----------E-------01/11/2015 01:20
```

I want to select all the possible combinations of events that appear in the table in the sequence of the recordDate by palletNumber. I tried various statements with Row Number, Over Partition but this did not get me close to what I am looking for... Any direction on where to go?

This would be the output table for example:

```
**Table 2**  
event1-- event2--
---A------B------
---B------C------
---C------D------
---A------C------
---C------E------
```

Thanks,

Comment: try `lead/lag (event) over (partition by palletNumber order by recordDate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the previous or next event using `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select event,
       lead(event) over (partition by palletnumber order by recorddate) as next_event
from datasample;
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates, I would be inclined to use `group by`, because this also gives the ability to count the number of times that each pair appears:

```
select event, next_event, count(*) as cnt
from (select event,
             lead(event) over (partition by palletnumber order by recorddate) as next_event
      from datasample
     ) ds
group by event, next_event;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know about lead/lag! Learn more every day.

Answer (score 0):

Use Case:

```
select case when palletNumber = 1 then event else null end as event1,
       case when palletNumber = 2 then event else null end as event2,
       recordDate
  from table1
```

Then you can work with the data using **lead**/**lag** or **sum**() / **group by** to get it in one row.

Assuming events 1/2 only have one record per date

```
  select recordDate, max (event1), max (event2)
    from (  select case when palletNumber = 1 then event else null end as event1,
                   case when palletNumber = 2 then event else null end as event2,
                   recordDate
              from table1
          order by recordDate) tab2
group by recordDate
```

Comment: It would work if I had a limited number of palletNumber but I have hundreds. I did use the lead/lag and group by however! Thanks